# Will a shutter half-press perform an autofocus while shooting video on an EOS 650D?

Tags: autofocus, canon-650d

Has Canon kept this feature or has it gone like the movie cropping mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to page 170 of the [*EOS Rebel T4i/650D Instruction Manual*](http://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/5/0300007695/01/eosrt4i-eos650d-im-c-en.pdf) you focus by using a shutter half-press before recording begins, then Movie Servo AF is active while recording. Page 191ff explains how to select other options.

[EOS Rebel T4i/650D Instruction Manual](http://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/5/0300007695/01/eosrt4i-eos650d-im-c-en.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for this good source (why didn't I think of it before!). On page 192, if I get it right, you just need to disable the Movie Servo to focus with the shutter button halfway pressed.